# Overwrite a text field in Blue Prism

Tags: blueprism

I need to fill some fields in a website with Blue Prism, however those fields are already filled in when I launch the site.

How can I overwrite them?

Comment: Use a Write stage.

Comment: I had issues where it was not overwriting the existing content in the field. This happened when I was using Navigate to send the keys or write the text. The answer esqew provided worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

As esqew mentioned using a Write stage to input data to HTML element should overwrite existing data. If it’s not the case, you can:

1. Click Centre onto Input Box
2. Send Keystrokes 10 x [Backspace] & 10 x [Delete] (number of keystrokes depends on length of input boxes)

This could be one action to clear input box values, therefore I suggest to create second action that reads data from input box to either check if it’s empty or validate input.

Comment: Checking length of text already in text box will add one more extra step. You can check the behavior of click center on input box (Usually the cursor will be placed at after the last character), then you can send `global send key event <{CTRL}A>{CTRL}` i.e  CTRL + A followed by another `global send key event {DEL}\{DELETE}`

Answer (score 0):

If clicking on each field makes the text editable (highlighted in blue..etc..), you can use that to highlight the existing text before using a Write stage to enter the text you want, which should then overwrite the existing text. Alternatively, you may want to try refreshing the page, using a different URL, or see if there is a button on the page to reset all the fields.